# angularjs with gulp and browserify

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I am using this https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular 
for scaffolding my project and I want to add browserify support to that 
what steps should I take ?

Comment: What steps have you already taken to get started? Have you tried anything yourself, or were you expecting us to just provide a solution?

Answer (score 0):

yeoman has a angulpify generator.  it's the best start i can think of for your question.  just start a boilerplate project and dissect it.

However, as someone who tried almost everything out there, unless you really need to include some node modules in your project stay away from it.  cuz actually for angularjs it really doesn't have any advantage.

Instead, you can try the concat style building.  much easier for testing and deployment.